# Need some advice with regexp

Tags: php, regex

I need to find and **remove** the newline sequences in some text and *join* the text together.

Before:

```
text 

some more text
```

After:

```
text some more text
```

Looks like logic should be like that:

```
[small letter]+[space]+[\n]+[space]+[small letter]
```

Can somebody help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, you know the pattern you want. Have you tried writing an expression?

Comment: you need to find end of line? then use \n. letter is \w space is \s. so /\w\s\n\s\w/. for only small letter [a-z]

Comment: I need to delete \n after seclection for get normal, solid, line of the text.And actualy I have no idea how regex works, thats why im asking )

Comment: More relevant http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to remove the newline sequence and join the text.

```
$str = "text\n\nsome more text";
$str = preg_replace('/\R+/', ' ', $str);
```

Output

```
text some more text
```

Comment: Unforchantly my text is much more complex that its shown in my example. So this code will not work (. I need to delete newline sign in the middle of the text only. Thats why I wrote about small letters and spaces.

Comment: Well you should post your complex data in your question.

Comment: For what you described though, you could see how this works out. `preg_replace('/(?<=[a-z]) \R+ (?=[a-z])/', ' ', $str);`